# How to access text in the DOM not wrapped in an HTML tag

Tags: javascript, dom

Using JavaScript, how can I access text located in the DOM but not wrapped in tags by itself.

For example:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="home.html">Home</a> |
  <a href="abou.html">About</a> |
  <a href="cont.html">Contact</a> |
  <a href="misc.html">Misc.</a>
  CopyrightNot @ 2016
</div>
```

How can I select "CopyrightNot @ 2016"?

Answer (score 1):

If the text you want to access with JavaScript is always after all the tags also in wrapped in the `div.container` tag, then use this:

`document.querySelector('div.container').lastChild.textContent.trim()`

Use the `querySelector` method to access the `div.container` element, then access the [`lastChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild) property on that element, which gives you the textNode you're looking for. Now just get the text on that element using the `textContent` property, and finally use the `trim` method to get rid of the leading and trailing spaces and line returns.

[JSBin example.](http://jsbin.com/hahidub/edit?html,js,console)

---

Likewise, if it's *before* all the other tags, use [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild):

`document.querySelector('div.container').firstChild.textContent.trim()`

And you can access ALL the child nodes, tags and text, within the `div.container` element using the [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) array.

```
// for loop
var con = document.querySelector('div.container');
for ( ii = 0, len = con.childNodes.length; ii < len; ii += 1 ) {
  console.log(con.childNodes[ii].textContent.trim());
}
```

If you know the position the text is located within the tags, such as third postion, then it's index will be `2` and you can access the text with:

`document.querySelector('div.container').childNodes[2].textContent.trim()`